# Lubuntu 18.04 on old laptop - Certain keys on keyboard don't work

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 LTS on an 10 year old Acer laptop. It's of course slower than modern notebooks, but still works like a reliable old mule.

Only issue I'm having is the keyboard. Certain keys won't work, but it's sort of irregular which ones, which makes me think it's not a hardware issue.

As I'm typing this the <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd> keys are not working. Oftentimes the <kbd>Space</kbd> and sometimes the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys don't work either, but then start to work after the laptop has been running for a while.

Sometimes, after the laptop has been running for a while, suddenly all keys work for a brief time, then those certain keys stop working again.

I tried running:

```bash
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

But it didn't help. I am helping myself with the *Onboard* keyboard application, but it's a pain.

Does anybody know this issue or have any idea what I could try to solve this?

Comment: It may be loose connection. You will have to open the laptop and reseat the keyboard cable. Or get it done by a professional.

Comment: Or see if you can use an external keyboard?